# How to access function scope variables in c++?

Tags: c++, scope-resolution

Global scoped variables can be accessed within a function using the :: operator. Since global scopes dont have a name, the left of :: could be empty. How will I access a variable defined in a function scope which is later overridden in a block within the function itself. In the following code, how will i access the variable initialised to 1 ?

```
extern int reused = 0;
int main()
{
    int reused = 1;
    {
        int reused = 2;
        cout << reused << endl; // how to get the reused inited to 1 here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe function.reused?

Comment: Perhaps by using *different* variable names?

Comment: You can't. Simple as that.

Comment: I would have thought you would get a warning about shadowing

Answer (score 3):

You can access the global `reused` anywhere inside `main` by using `::reused`. However, there is no way to use the second `reused` inside the block where the third `reused` is declared. The language does not provide a mechanism for that.